# prevent logging of message body Twilio

Tags: twilio

I have disabled Request Inspector, but I still see the message body in the logs. What else do I need to do to prevent the message body from being logged?

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here. It sounds like this might be a good use case for `redact`. An example in Python:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"
auth_token  = "{{ auth_token }}"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

client.messages.redact("MM800f449d0399ed014aae2bcc0cc2f2ec")
```

You can see examples in other languages [here in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-post-example-1).